# ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE on Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ssl, websocket

I have a website that uses [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) for client-server communication and has a certificate issued by *Let's Encrypt*. Other browsers work, but Google Chrome (on Linux) gives the error `ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE` in the console. Disabling TLS 1.3 lets users circumvent this error. I am using the latest stable version.

[This](https://superuser.com/a/1217757) answer suggests the problem is when Chrome detects *"buggy middleware"* but I don't know what exactly Chrome is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with Mono. Mono uses BoringSSL in newer versions but it isn't turned on by default in older versions. On newer Linux distributions you can do `export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls` but that didn't work for me because the gcc compiler on CentOS 6 (version 4.4) is too old and doesn't support `align` which is necessary to compile BoringSSL.

First I installed gcc 4.8 with instructions from here: https://gist.github.com/stephenturner/e3bc5cfacc2dc67eca8b

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo
sudo yum install devtoolset-2
scl enable devtoolset-2 bash
```

Then I downloaded the latest release package of mono from their website (currently 5.12.0.226): http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/linux/

```
wget https://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-5.12.0.226.tar.bz2
tar xvf mono-5.12.0.226.tar.bz2
cd mono-5.12.0.226
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Just in case, I did `export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls` too, although I don't think it's necessary, but regardless if you look at the output at the end of `./configure` it should tell you if BTLS is enabled.

This also fixed the same problem with recent Firefox update 60.0.0.2.